# Adding section to PE binary using Stud_Pe

Tags: windows, pe, binary, section

I want to be able to accurately add a section to a binary by hand, without tools.

I am using [Stud_Pe](http://www.cgsoftlabs.ro/studpe.html) for adding a section to a binary. While this work, I feel it's important to be able to do this myself or at least understand it in it's entirety.

Added Section/Stud here called **.test** with a size of 0x2000 [image]

Something I noticed is that the when I do a bindiff on the newly added section There is always extra bytes added to this. Why is this? 
[image]

I thought there might be a pattern but it seems random and the sizes have to be exact , so I am curious if someone already knows.

Here is a difference list based on the bytes added. 
Why is this happening?

```
0x2000 2  bytes
0x3000 14 bytes
0x4000 10 bytes
0x5000 4  bytes
0x6000 18 bytes
0x7000 2  bytes
0x8000 16 bytes
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this post out it may be helpful http://ge0-it.blogspot.fr/2012/08/adding-section-to-your-pe-easy-way.html

Code snippet from source above:

```
VOID PortableExecutable::AddSection(PortableExecutable::SectionHeader& newSectionHeader) {
    DWORD dwRawSectionOffset = (DWORD)GetFileSize();

    /* Aligns dwRawSectionOffset to OptionalHeader.FileAlignment */
    dwRawSectionOffset += this->m_imageNtHeaders.OptionalHeader.FileAlignment - (dwRawSectionOffset % this->m_imageNtHeaders.OptionalHeader.FileAlignment);

    /* Does the whole header's length overflows OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders? */
    if(
        (sizeof(IMAGE_DOS_HEADER) + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS) + (this->m_imageNtHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections * sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER)))
        > this->m_imageNtHeaders.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders
        ) {

            /* If it's the case, add free space */
            AddFreeSpaceAfterHeaders( this->m_imageNtHeaders.OptionalHeader.FileAlignment );

            /* Adding 'FileAlignment' value to SizeOfHeaders fields then */
            this->m_imageNtHeaders.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders += this->m_imageNtHeaders.OptionalHeader.FileAlignment;

    }

    newSectionHeader.SetPointerToRawData(dwRawSectionOffset);

    /* Adding the new section header */
    this->m_sectionHeaders.push_back(newSectionHeader);

    /* Incrementing the 'NumberOfSections' field */
    ++this->m_imageNtHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections;

    /* Adding to SizeOfImage the SectionAlignment value */
    this->m_imageNtHeaders.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage += this->m_imageNtHeaders.OptionalHeader.SectionAlignment;

    /* Rewriting the whole headers */
    m_stream.seekg(this->m_imageDosHeader.e_lfanew, std::ios::beg);
    m_stream.write((const char*)&this->m_imageNtHeaders, sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS));

    /* Rewriting the section headers then */
    std::vector<PortableExecutable::SectionHeader>::iterator it =
        this->m_sectionHeaders.begin();

    while(it != this->m_sectionHeaders.end()) {
        m_stream.write((const char*)&it->ImageSectionHeader(), sizeof(IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER));
        ++it;
    }

    /* Finally adding 'FileAlignment' bytes to the end of the file,
    which actually corresponds to the section's memory space! */
    m_stream.seekg(this->m_sectionHeaders.at( this->m_sectionHeaders.size()-1).GetPointerToRawData(), std::ios::beg);

    char* bytes = new char[this->m_imageNtHeaders.OptionalHeader.FileAlignment];
    ::memset(bytes, '\0', this->m_imageNtHeaders.OptionalHeader.FileAlignment);
    m_stream.write(bytes, this->m_imageNtHeaders.OptionalHeader.FileAlignment);
    delete[] bytes;
}
```